# Why does this PHP object append items onto itself?

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm new to OOP and seem to be stuck on something that i'm sure is very simple, but I don't understand what's happening.

The below example code:

```
class add_some {

    static $arr = array('a', 'b');

    static $new_arr = array();

    public static function iterate() {

        foreach (self::$arr as $v) {
            self::$new_arr[] = $v;
        }

    }

}

for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {

    // instantiate the object
    $add_some = new add_some;

    // launch the method that copies items from $arr to $new_arr
    $add_some::iterate();

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($add_some::$new_arr);
    echo "</pre>";

    unset($add_some);

}
```

Goes through a loop and adds the items which are in **$arr** to **$new_arr**, it basically copies all items from $arr to $new_arr

The code instantiates a new object and executes the method iterate() which copies items from $arr to $new_arr 3 times.

Each iteration creates a new object $add_some = new add_some; so each iteration **should just produce**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
```

**But for some reason the object keeps growing with each iteration.... And I have no idea why**.. I tried destroying the object (unset) and not sure if I should be doing something else.

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
)
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [4] => a
    [5] => b
)
```

Comment: +1 to somewhat offset the downvotes, the question is not so bad and it doesn't deserve them. The problem is clearly described and it's not unreasonable for somebody new to OOP to be confused by this.

Comment: thank you, I was a bit confused about the downvotes, I did 2 courses on OOP and albeit them being beginner courses there was no mention of the static properties being maintained in memory even after the object is destroyed. The question may be helpful to other newbies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the static method by use of the `::` (Paamayim Nekudotayim), you should be using `->` and not using a static function.

Static means, keep this around globally, it is not instantiated each time you call new, it is `static`.

You can for example call a static method like so:

```
class MyClass {
  static function MyFunc() { echo 'Stuff'; }
}

MyClass::MyFunc()
```

There is no need to (nor should you) create an instance of `MyClass` to call the static `MyFunc`.

Each time you call `iterate` it is appending the global static array `$arr`

The correct way to do this would be

```
class add_some {
  private $x = 1;
  private $arr = array('a', 'b');
  public  $new_arr = array();

  public function iterate() {
    foreach ($this->arr as $v) {
        $this->new_arr[] = $v;
    }
  }
}

for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  $add_some = new add_some();
  $add_some->iterate();
  print_r($add_some->new_arr);
}
```

Comment: Is it common for php developers to refer to :: as Paamayim Nekudotayim?It's really weird if this is the case. It's insane that php development team didn't bother to fix it through 4 major versions.

Comment: What is there to fix? Paamayim Nekudotayim means double colon in Hebrew... http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: there's a whole discussion about it, even though we own a lot to Zend developers I think a universally used english term would be better suited

Comment: btw a very hacky approach to this would be to unset the static property, by doing $add_some::$new_arr = null; at the end of each iteration

Comment: @Geoffrey Being a native Hebrew speaker I know what it means. I don't really know how to respond to you thinking it's normal to have Hebrew in PHP language reference, maybe add some Chinese, Greek and Aramaic as well. It doesn't even sound good in Hebrew, it means "twice colon" not "double colon".

Comment: @Oleg I really don't know why you raised this here instead of at php.net, it is completely off topic.

Comment: @RobertSinclair: True, but that would not have informed the OP what was wrong with their code, nor caused them to investigate what `static` means.

Comment: I think it falls under "Request clarification from the author" and in any case comments are second class citizens and not really important. *P.S.* Robert Sinclair is the OP.